# Issue with WiX installer configuration and Newton.JSON nuget package

Tags: wix, installation, json.net

I'm making an Setup project using WiX and my project uses the Newton.JSON library. I've not referenced the Newton library in WiX however it is fully referenced in my application.

This is the error I'm receiving (Sorry for the image, unable to copy paste the code) :

[image: error]

Could someone please save me, I've been pulling my hair about this for a few hours now, nothing I try seems to work. Tried deleting all bin and ob files, deleted packing.config, deleting the bin and obj from both my project and the installer project. Then trying to reinstall Newton.JSON. Still no joy.

Here is my package.config file currently :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <packages>
 <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
 </packages>
```

Here is the link to my setup project xml - http://nopaste.info/bcbc2048a6.html (for some reason SO doesnt let me add it as code.

As you can see the packages property does indeed have the newton.json reference.

Anyone have the same issue at all? So it isn't just me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to assemble all dependencies manually in the folder you wish to install to and try to run the application from there to see what files need to be installed. Register any components that need registration such as COM Interop files. Most .NET applications work if you copy all referenced assemblies to the installation directory. The EXE will use the local folder as default search path.

Comment: Ill give this a go, I never thought of that. Again I've never made a wix installation before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include dependencies in your installer package. WiX doesn't automatically pull in project references.